# javascript: sorting through a list of dictionaries and returning the highest value of a specific key

Tags: javascript

I have a list like:

```
var x = [{var: 'test', id:1},{var: 'test2', id:2}, {var: 'test', id: 3}];
```

I've looked at the docs for reduce but not sure how to apply it to this data structure.

I want to map over the list and look at each value of `id` and set `x` to be the highest value.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean? I put that into the browser and I don't get any errors

Comment: thats not a duplicate, that is iterating over ONE dictionary, not a LIST of dictionaries

Comment: `x.reduce((p, c) => { return c.id > p ? c.id : p }, 0)`?

Comment: @morgan really? But even if it works you should not use a reserved keyword like `var` as identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method for that.

```js
var x = [{var: 'test', id:1},{var: 'test2', id:2}, {var: 'test', id: 3}];

var res = x
  // iterate over the array
  .reduce(function(prev, next) {
    // compare the previous value with the current object property

    // use ternary syntax
    return prev < next.id ? next.id : prev;
    
    // or use Math.max
    // return Math.max(prev, next.id);
    
    // set initial value as the least possible value
    // since you want to find the highest
  }, -Infinity);

console.log(res);
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var x = [{var: 'test', id:1},{var: 'test2', id:2}, {var: 'test', id: 3}];

var res = x.reduce((p, n)=> Math.max(p, n.id), -Infinity);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @morgan why should i?

Comment: @Jonasw because your initial comment made no sense

Comment: @morgan yeah, okay i admit that i made a mistake there :/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = [{
  var: 'test',
  id: 1
}, {
  var: 'test2',
  id: 2
}, {
  var: 'test',
  id: 3
}];

var y = x.reduce(function (a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b.id)
}, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);

console.log('y : ', y);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the property `id` and return the object with the greater `id`. At the end take the value of `id`.

The advantage is, no unreal start value, becaue it checks from start the first two elements and then any other against the actual max object.

```js
var array = [{ 'var': 'test', id: 1 }, { 'var': 'test2', id: 2 }, { 'var': 'test', id: 3 }],
    max = array.reduce((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? a : b).id;
    
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Math.max, a spread operator and .map:

```
const result = Math.max(...x.map(el=>el.id));
```